# Firestore permissions; checking if a user is in an array

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In Cloud Firestore, I have a collection of documents with an array field containing all of the users that should have read permission on that document. My simplified security rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /collection_name/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.listOfIds.toSet();
    }
  }
}
```

A sample simplified document is:

```
{
  listOfIds: ["uid1", "uid2"]
}
```

Using the rules simulator to perform a get, reads work as expected. However, executing a similar query using the Android API returns a permission denied error. I think I'm constraining my query in the same ways the rules are (which is a [requirement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) of Firestore; it doesn't filter out documents that the user can't read for you).

```
firestoreClient.collection("collection_name")
    .whereArrayContains("listOfIds", firebaseUid)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, Firestore thought the query wasn't properly constrained to the defined read permissions. It was the `.toSet()` that threw it off. Removing that resulted in the behavior I expected.

Why did I have `.toSet()` to begin with? I had erroneously thought that converting the array into a set was a requirement to use the `in` operator. That operator [works with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) as well as sets.

Comment: It might be worth reporting as a bug with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Reported it, thanks for the suggestion. It sounds like they may update the documentation for the in operator. Not sure if they're going to change the validation logic to realize the query is properly constrained even with toSet